# HttpPostedFileBase with PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, httppostedfilebase

I have a main view which contains a partial view. The model of partial view has 1 property called "HttpPostedFileBase file", together with other properties

However when the main-view get posted, all the other properties in that model get correct value, but the "HttpPostedFileBase file" is null. I already set the name of  to be the same as parameter. Also even Request.Files give me 0 number of files.

What have I done wrong?

P.S. My main-view actually has 2 partial views. One PV has the same model as main-view. The 2nd one is what I mentioned above. The model contains a list of objects and HttpPostedFileBase file. Code like this:

```
public class MyPartialViewModel
{
    public List<MyObject> objInfos { get; set; }


    public ICollection<HttpPostedFileBase> file { get; set; }
}
```

And in the PV I looply use @Html.EditFor(model=>model.objInfos[i]) to bind it to a template.

So in main-view post method, I could get "objInfos" list & all ojects' value correct. But just NULL for "file".

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` as one of the `htmlAttributes` in the `@Html.BeginForm()` helper.

**EDIT: To not make a visual full postback:**

[AJAX FILE Upload in MVC3 using iFrame](http://www.dustinhorne.com/post/2011/11/16/AJAX-File-Uploads-with-jQuery-and-MVC-3.aspx)

In this right moment I'm using this approach, actually implementing this as we write.

Comment: Actually I added like this:  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    UpdateTargetId = "mainSection",
    OnSuccess = "handleSuccess",
    OnFailure = "handleError"
}, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{}

Comment: Ahh, that is the problem. It is needed a full postback in order to successfully upload the file. It is not possible to do an upload using Ajax.

Comment: I previously use iframe (replace 2nd PV) which works fine..... and because I want to put iframe & 1st PV validation result together, I found it's too hard to do in iframe... that why I changed 2nd one to PV as well ..... :(

Answer (score 1):

I've just come across the same problem, and have worked around it by placing an extra parameter in the ActionResult to take the file upload parameter.

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyActionResult(MyViewModel viewModel, HttpPostedFileBase myFileToUpload)
    {
        myViewModel.PartialViewModel.MyFileToUpload = myFileToUpload;
            //manually bind MyFileToUpload;
            //for some reason, because it's in the Partial View and it's of type HttpPostedFileBase, it won't post.

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Just for context:

My PartialViewModel contains the code:

```
    public HttpPostedFileBase MyFileToUpload{ get; set; }
```

and PartialView the code:

```
    <div class="editor-item">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyFileToUpload)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyFileToUpload)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Finally, I have an EditorTemplate Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/HttpPostedFileBase.cshtml:

```
@model HttpPostedFileBase
<input type="file" name="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" />
```

It's a workaround, not a solution, but does enable you to get the file uploaded while leaving the HttpPostedFileBase in the PartialViewModel.